# css not working properly after forbidding a folder

Tags: .htaccess

Good day. Got a problem here. I'm trying to forbid a folder and i succeeded from it,the problem for now is, I can't use it anymore.My web design does not work when I included it. How can i fix this?
I have tried to use `options -indexes` but it would not block the access if someone knows the file name like `folder/css/index.css`.
How can I block a user from accesing it without affecting my web-design.

Comment: Please don't be too harsh. i just wan't to keep my designs so no one can use it except for me. I had a hard time doing it so I believe it's worth securing it. Don't want others to use my design, that is why i'm asking for help. thanks in advance

Comment: When i use this code i cannot access my own design anymore. i cannot include it on my website.`<FilesMatch "\.css$"> 
Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 0):

By blocking access to the folder, you stopped the browser from being able to access it, which it needs to do in order to display it.

You won't ever be able to totally stop users from directly accessing the css file, if they're determined enough. The browser has to download the css file (so too can the users).

There are steps you can take to make it harder though. You could obfuscate/minify the CSS code to make it harder for people to understand - http://www.cssobfuscator.com

You could also check to make sure the referrer header is your website to prevent hotlinking - see http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/

Ultimately though, it will always be accessible and visible to your users

Answer (score 0):

You can forbid access to the folder using the following in your /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !your_ip_address_here 
RewriteRule ^folder/css/index\.css - [F,L,NC]
```

That means only your IP address will be able to access the protected folder.

Comment: How can i make it work ? i have copied my remote address using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and pasted at after `!` but even i cannot access it now even the index.html is forbidden